# Hiding child elements if they contain a href == #

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I hide each `#wrapper div.part` if its `a href` attribute equals `#`? I tried this and it's not working:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('#wrapper > div.part a').each(function() {
    if (this == "#") {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="part">
    <p>Some text here...</p>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <p>Some text here...</p>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <p>Some text here...</p>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm new to jQuery so sorry if it's basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can select the `a` element by its `href`, then get the `closest()` parent `.part` and `hide()` it. Try this:

```
$('#wrapper .part a[href="#"]').closest('.part').hide();
```

```js
$('#wrapper .part a[href="#"]').closest('.part').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="part">
    <p>Some text here...</p>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <p>Some text here...</p>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <p>Some text here...</p>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <p>Some text here...</p>
    <a href="somepage.html">Link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or even more succinctly, thanks to @T.J. Crowder:

```
$('#wrapper .part:has(a[href="#"])').hide();
```

Comment: Or `#wrapper .part:has(a[href="#"])` for a jQuery-specific selector.

Comment: What a champ - will practice my selectors & filters :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Below is what you are looking for:

```js
$("document").ready(function () {
    $('#wrapper > div.part a').each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('href') == "#") {
                $(this).hide();
            }
            else {
                $(this).show();
            };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="part">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="part">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="part">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
        <a href="">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For my suggestion simply use with in `css`**

```css
#wrapper .part a[href='#']{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
      <div class="part">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="part">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="part">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**For javascript**

You could use like this `$(this).attr('href')`

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('#wrapper > div.part a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == "#") {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="part">
    <p>Some text here...</p>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <p>Some text here...</p>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <p>Some text here...</p>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("document").ready(function () {
    $('#wrapper > div.part a').filter(function() {
           return $(this).attr('href') == "#"
    }).parent('div.part').hide()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="part">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="part">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="part">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
        <a href="#1">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

1. use `.filter()`
2. return matching a with href == #
3. hide its parent with class part

Answer (score 0):

A example  with a link to google...

With the attr() function, you can read specific attributes of a element. 
The each function also provides the current element as an argument to the function. You should avoid using "this" in nested function, as it can be different depending on context.

```js
$('#wrapper > div.part a').each(function(index,element) {
            if ($(element).attr("href") == "#") {
                $(element).hide();
            }
            else {
                $(element).show();
            };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="part">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="part">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
        <a href="http://google.de">Link to google</a>
    </div>
    <div class="part">
        <p>Some text here...</p>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```